# UnsatisfiedDependencyException running Spring app in Kotlin

Tags: sql, spring, kotlin, spring-jdbc

I have 2 files for sql db to run when i start spring sever using IDE.
I keep getting this error
`Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home***/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)`

the issue is with these 2 lines

```
ALTER TABLE Taco ADD FOREIGN KEY (taco_order) REFERENCES Taco_Order(id);
ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id);
```

once i comment them everything goes well... but can't figure out the issue with them
how can i fix this?

here is the whole file

```
create table if not exists Taco_Order (
  id identity not null,
  delivery_Name varchar(50) not null,
  delivery_Street varchar(50) not null,
  delivery_City varchar(50) not null,
  delivery_State varchar(2) not null,
  delivery_Zip varchar(10) not null,
  cc_number varchar(16) not null,
  cc_expiration varchar(5) not null,
  cc_cvv varchar(3) not null,
  placed_at timestamp not null
);
create table if not exists Taco (
  id identity not null,
  name varchar(50) not null,
  taco_order bigint not null,
  taco_order_key bigint not null,
  created_at timestamp not null
);
create table if not exists Ingredient_Ref (
  ingredient varchar(4) not null,
  taco bigint not null,
  taco_key bigint not null
);
create table if not exists Ingredient (
  id varchar(4) not null,
  name varchar(25) not null,
  type varchar(10) not null
);
ALTER TABLE Taco ADD FOREIGN KEY (taco_order) REFERENCES Taco_Order(id);
ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id);
```

UPDATE: Data.sql file

```
delete from Ingredient_Ref;
delete from Taco;
delete from Taco_Order;
delete from Ingredient;
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('FLTO', 'Flour Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('COTO', 'Corn Tortilla', 'WRAP');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('GRBF', 'Ground Beef', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('CARN', 'Carnitas', 'PROTEIN');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('TMTO', 'Diced Tomatoes', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('LETC', 'Lettuce', 'VEGGIES');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('CHED', 'Cheddar', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('JACK', 'Monterrey Jack', 'CHEESE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('SLSA', 'Salsa', 'SAUCE');
insert into Ingredient (id, name, type) values ('SRCR', 'Sour Cream', 'SAUCE');
```

UPDATE: Error Message after adding the last 2 lines

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v3.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

2022-12-06T15:57:27.835+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] sia.tacocloud.TacoCloudApplicationKt     : Starting TacoCloudApplicationKt using Java 17.0.5 with PID 5993 (/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main started by saher in /home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud)
2022-12-06T15:57:27.840+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] sia.tacocloud.TacoCloudApplicationKt     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2022-12-06T15:57:27.901+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2022-12-06T15:57:27.901+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-12-06T15:57:28.933+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-12-06T15:57:28.942+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-12-06T15:57:28.942+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.1]
2022-12-06T15:57:28.981+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-12-06T15:57:28.982+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1079 ms
2022-12-06T15:57:29.013+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : tacoCloud - Starting...
2022-12-06T15:57:29.174+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : tacoCloud - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:tacoCloud user=SA
2022-12-06T15:57:29.175+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : tacoCloud - Start completed.
2022-12-06T15:57:29.185+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:tacoCloud'
2022-12-06T15:57:29.343+02:00  WARN 5993 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'designTacoController' defined in file [/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main/sia/tacocloud/controller/DesignTacoController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'ingredientsRepositoryImpl' defined in file [/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main/sia/tacocloud/repositories/IngredientsRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action/taco-cloud/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)
2022-12-06T15:57:29.343+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : tacoCloud - Shutdown initiated...
2022-12-06T15:57:29.355+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : tacoCloud - Shutdown completed.
2022-12-06T15:57:29.357+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-12-06T15:57:29.372+02:00  INFO 5993 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-12-06T15:57:29.394+02:00 ERROR 5993 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'designTacoController' defined in file [/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main/sia/tacocloud/controller/DesignTacoController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'ingredientsRepositoryImpl' defined in file [/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main/sia/tacocloud/repositories/IngredientsRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action/taco-cloud/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sia.tacocloud.TacoCloudApplicationKt.main(TacoCloudApplication.kt:12) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'ingredientsRepositoryImpl' defined in file [/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring in Action/taco-cloud/build/classes/kotlin/main/sia/tacocloud/repositories/IngredientsRepositoryImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action/taco-cloud/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:793) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:242) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action/taco-cloud/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1405) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:880) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:784) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #6 of URL [file:/home/saher/kotlin/Spring/Spring%20in%20Action/taco-cloud/build/resources/main/schema.sql]: ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applySchemaScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:98) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "PRIMARY KEY | UNIQUE (ID)" not found; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE Ingredient_Ref ADD FOREIGN KEY (ingredient) REFERENCES Ingredient(id) [90057-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:632) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:258) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:72) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTable.update(AlterTable.java:46) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:169) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:252) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    ... 61 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you for copying/pasting the error message - that's good.  Q: Is it the COMPLETE error text?  Does the error say WHY it failed (e.g. "permissions")?  Q: What database are you using?  Have you checked the DB logs, and/or your Spring Server (e.g. Tomcat) logs?  We absolutely need to find a log that gives us better diagnostic info.

Comment: Many times adding an FK it fails because the relationships are not there correctly to support the FK (Missing data in parent table) or you have more data in child table that does not exist in parent table.

Comment: Do you get the error while the tables are empty?

Comment: I added the error message in full...

Comment: @paulsm4 i just updated the question with the full error message

Comment: @Brad actually the code is from a book for Spring, the book is in Java and i'm doing it in Kotlin....

Comment: @marcothesane i get the errors when i start the application, technically yes the tables should be empty.

Comment: by the way i'm using the com.h2database:h2 as db

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was solved by adding a constraint primary key to the `ingredient` table.

```
alter table ingredient add PRIMARY key (id);
```

now it is working so well...